Azure Cosmos DB takes multiple attempts or inconsistent while updating the record
I am trying to update the cosmos db record using PatchItemAsync method. The caveat is the HTTP method is PUT and we need to update a couple of properties of the record and not the whole record so we were using PatchItemAsync. We can't use PATCH method because one of our older implementation is also dependent on that controller. When we are updating the record sometimes it takes 20-30 seconds to update and sometimes it takes more than one call from postman to update those properties. Can you guys help me with this issue ?
public async Task<T> PatchItem<T>(Cosmos.CosmosDBContainerType cosmosDBContainerType, string itemId, dynamic partitionKey, List<PatchOperation> patchOperation)
{
  Container container = this.GetContainer(cosmosDBContainerType);

  patchOperation.Add(PatchOperation.Replace("/lastUpdatedOn", DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.ToUnixTimeSeconds()));  
  var response = await container.PatchItemAsync<T>(itemId, new PartitionKey(partitionKey), patchOperation); return response.Resource;

}

This is the code and I expect this to update the cosmos db record. When I am trying to update it using the localhost url it works perfectly but the deployed api is giving me the issue that I have mentioned above.
